# bind dropdown and textbox search into single serach using JQuery in C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a `dropdown` box having enabled/disabled option. and also have a `textbox` to search the value to list the filtered value in the corresponding index page.

Already i have a code to filter using `textbox` search but now i have to filter the values using combination of `dropdown` list and `textbox` search in a single search.

```
function onSearch() {
    var q = $("#txtSearchString").val();
    var drop = $("dropRoles").val();
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.dataSource.query({
                    page: 1,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    filter: {

                          logic: "or",
                          filters: [
                                 { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: q },
                                 { field: "Id", operator: "contains", value: q },                                          
                                 { field: "Type", operator: "contains", value: q },
                                 { field: "Usage", operator: "contains", value: q },
                                 { field: "BuilderName", operator: "contains", value: q },
                                 { field: "Status", operator: "contains", value: q },
                                 { field: "Sgroup", operator: "contains", value: q },
                                 { field: "IsActive", operator: "contains", value: drop }
                                   ]

                             }

                         });
                     }
```

here, IsActive is a dropdownbox field.

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropRoles", new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem() { Text= "Enabled", Value = true.ToString()},
    new SelectListItem() { Text= "Disabled", Value = false.ToString()}
}, "Select ...", new { @class = "form-control-list", @id = "dropRoles", style = "width: 120px;hight= 90px" })
```

In database i have stored the bool value for "ISActive" column.

My questions are:
1.How to change the enabled/disabled `dropdown` values into bool value for the searching purpose.
2. How to combine both `dropdown` and `textbox` into a single search. ("and" search)